# curl --verbose works but ordinary curl fails

Tags: docker, curl, https

I want to connect to an API inside a docker container.

`curl --verbose https://api_url` works, but `curl https://api_url` hangs and times out.

Also the end line of `curl --verbose https://api_url` gives me this message:

> - Connection #0 to host api.quran.com left intact

The URL I'm trying to connect to is `https://api.quran.com/api/v3/chapters`.

Other APIs works just fine inside the container. And I can also `curl` that API from my local machine (outside the container).

And inside the container, the `fetch` of Node.js fails too.

What can be the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: can you please share the container image/name you are using. If it's your own image, it would be great if you can also share the Dockerfile. Are you using any specific networking params for docker?

Btw, would be happy to help you in any project related to Quran.

Comment: Thank you so much @akathimi. This is a personal project of trying to understand Quran.